# I want to put func internetChanged in the other file. (about reachabiliy)

Tags: swift, reachability

I have many viewController will use reachability,
so i want to put in the other file,
this is my code

```
func internetConnect() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(internetChanged), name: Notification.Name.reachabilityChanged, object: reachability)
    do{
        try reachability.startNotifier()
    }catch{
        print("could not start reachability notifier")
    }
}

@objc func internetChanged(note: Notification) {
    let reachability = note.object as! Reachability
    if reachability.connection != .none{
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.internetLabel.isHidden = true
        }
    }else{
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.internetLabel.isHidden = false
        }
    }
}
```

but if i put in the other file,
it can't catch the label,
if i uesd

```
func internetConnect(label:UILabel) {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(internetChanged), name: Notification.Name.reachabilityChanged, object: reachability)
    do{
        try reachability.startNotifier()
    }catch{
        print("could not start reachability notifier")
    }
}
```

the label still can't put in

```
selector: #selector(internetChanged)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your view controller's name from the first file is `ViewController1`.

If you add this function not in `extension ViewController1 { ... }`  - then for selector you need to explicitly specify view controller where this method is at.

So if `internetChanged` is in `ViewController1`, then to use it from another file - use `#selector(ViewController1.internetChanged)`

Answer (score 0):

This question is not clear but you can use a subclass for all your viewcontrollers and add your connection methods there. And do not forget to remove observer when you are done with the controller.

[Here a reference for subclassing.](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Inheritance.html)